# Change color of selected form-fields with VBA in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, form-fields

Is there any way to globally change the selection color of all form-fields in MS Word? I have a test form that I fill out as I'm doing a test. My eyes go back and forth between the meters I read and the form I fill out. I then tab to the next field to fill out and read another meter. The default colors of the form-fields between when the field is selected for input and when it is not is not very different. I find myself trying to find my place again when looking at the form again.

Is there any way to globally change the color of all form-fields so that the color when it is selected is much different than the color when not selected? Thanks.

Keep in mind that the form is protected so that only changes to the fields are allowed. So I will have to unprotect the document before I can change it and then reprotect it after I'm done. This much I can do. I can change colors when I enter and exit a field. But this slows down how fast I can fill out the form. So I was hoping there was a property I could set to change only the selection color and cycle through all fields when the document is first opened. Any suggestions out there?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Asking questions here is typically done after you have read the documentation and tried to solve the issue yourself first. After which, you ask your question by presenting a sample of what you have tried. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question to adhere to the StackOverflow standards.

Comment: I'm looking for the property that changes the color of a form-field only when it is selected if such exists. Also, I'd like to set the selected color of all form-fields in the entire document at once if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the only options for form fields are grey or uncolored. To switch between those 2, VBA is not required. Instead, choose **Developer>Legacy Forms** and click the 5th icon from the left **Form Field Shading** (looks like an **a** with hatch marks around it).

Comment: Actually, there is a light gray color when the field is not selected, and a dark gray color when it is selected. So some property or other is changing the color. Also, I am able to change the color to, say, green using a macro on entering the field. And I can change it back to gray on exiting the field. So it does seem possible to change the color. But this may be the same color properties that's being changed on entrance and exit.

Comment: The color change when an object is selected is not usually considered to be an attribute of the object, but of the selection process. You can try selecting the form field and applying a highlight. It doesn't actually change the color of the field, but it hides the original grey.

Comment: How about the field boarder. Is the boarder color/size when the field is selected a property that can be set when the document is first opened? Thanks.

Comment: Form fields are ancient controls and their appearance is not part of the VBA object model.